# How can I iterate through a large ActiveMQ queue?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have a queue containing almost 250,000 messages. I'd like to iterate through the messages without removing them. I've used `QueueBrowser` for this, but it makes only the first 200 elements available. `QueueBrowser`'s Javadoc explains that it "peeks" at messages from the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies in the Destination Policy in play for your broker.  By default the broker will only page in 200 message for a browser to avoid using up all available memory and avoid impacting overall performance.  You can increase this number via your own DestinationPolicy in activemq.xml, see the documentation page [here](http://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies.html).